# What use do Skyshards have?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I have found about two Skyshards. I tried searching but am too immersed in the game.

What can Skyshards be used for? So far I have 2/3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time you find 3 Skyshards you will gain a new Skill-Point.

The locations of all the Skyshards can be found [here](http://teso.mmorpg-life.com/database/skyshard-locations-map/).

Comment: @ヴァイシャリ I think it's not really worth farming at lower levels but once you reach 50, sure why not? You will gain a lot of skyshards from leveling anyways and if you like exploration you will find even more.

Comment: While it really shouldn't be an "answer", I agree with Odif below. The add-on http://www.curse.com/teso-addons/teso/skyshards puts all of the skyshards on your map in a similar fashion to dungens and other objects on your map. Shards that have yet to be discovered are black with a white outline and skyshards you have found are white with a black outline.

Answer (score 2):

Actually i suggest everybody install this addon (or something like it): http://www.curse.com/teso-addons/teso/skyshards

I have found it to be insanely useful. Get lvl 10. Enter into some battleground which your alliance controls most of - and get tons of skysharding action :)